# Keyboard dismissed when showing alertdialog in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a text field in my Flutter app where a user can enter their name. They can press "submit". But when a name is too short, I show a dialog.

The problem: when the dialog is shown the keyboard gets automatically dismissed and the alert dialog jumps from above (when the keyboard is still active) to below (when the keyboard isn't active anymore, half a second later).

Is it possible to keep the keyboard active when showing a dialog.
Code:

````
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
                 title: Text("Error"),
                 content:
                     Text("Name too short"),
     ));
```
````

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Could you attach it to the question? ^

Comment: well, it will pop up the dialog, while the dialog get closed, keyboard will popUp again by default.

Comment: but i want keyboard stay when alertbox comes. and make keyboard as barrier like android alertbox. Is there any alternative way?